# New TypeScript React app using Vite - JSX.IntrinsicElements errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, vite

I'm trying out Vite with React TS and using their [official documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide). The app builds and runs, however viewing it in VS Code shows a whole bunch of `Property 'div' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)` errors.

I've created a new React TS application using `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` and am not getting this issue.

Looking at [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide) once again, they've got a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-azsc25?file=src%2FApp.tsx&terminal=dev) link that exhibits the same issue, so this means that this is not my environment that's the problem.

Am I missing something? Surely this should not be a problem for official Vite documentation? Please note however, that I'm new to React and Vite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so it seems that updating the tsconfig.json from `"moduleResolution": "bundler"` to `"moduleResolution": "node"` resolves this. I don't yet fully understand what this does, neither do I understand why Vite does not create a compatible configuration out of the box. I'll response if/when I found out more.

Edit: updating VS Code fixed the issue

Comment: Seems not even to be so well documented what bundler is doing:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html
Here it says to strategies: Node or Classic but nothing about bundler